# Passing form class instead of an instance to Django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'd like to pass a **form class** instead of **unbound form instance** to the template. It seems to be working, but I'm not sure if it's a safe way to do it.

The reason I need this is because I want to use django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset built-in view with my extended template which needs also another form (providing alternative workflow).

So in my urls.py, I do this:

```
url(r'^password/reset/$', views.password_reset, {'extra_context': {'my_form': MyForm}} ),
```

Do you think it is alright? Are there any possible (hidden) problems I could later encounter? Thanks.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't explain anything. There's no point in passing a class unless you instantiate it at some point. You'd better show what you're doing with it.

Comment: My point is, that normally you instantiate form class per request basis (I think it's generally not recommended to reuse instances in multiple requests). But since I'm passing a class, I thought Django might automatically instantiate it on every request.